# Running Odoo Application from Ubuntu

Tags: python, postgresql, ubuntu, virtual-machine, odoo

I have a project to do using Odoo in Ubuntu, they sent me an image file with a virtual machine containing Ubuntu and all the apps pre-installed for Odoo (Python, PostgreSQL, PyCharm etc.). The problem is that I can't find out how to access Odoo via browser or run an Odoo application (I got some finished projects too). I tried accessing the Odoo server with the default 127.0.0.1:8069 but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run odoo on an Ubuntu server.
I'd start with checking if you have a odoo service.

```
sudo service odoo status

Status of odoo: running
```

This is what I put into my jira comments from when I was installing odoo.

```
wget -O - https://nightly.odoo.com/odoo.key | apt-key add -
echo "deb http://nightly.odoo.com/8.0/nightly/deb/ ./" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update && apt-get install odoo
```

Comment: It says: odoo: unrecognized service

Comment: Then I'd ask the people who sent the file how to access odoo.

Comment: Or start making your own virtual from scratch.

Comment: Cheers ... I installed odoo myself on my server. It involved adding in the odoo repository, updating apt-get and then getting the latest builds from odoo.

Comment: I even tried that but I'm currently stuck on installing odoo, the terminal just says: SEtting up odoo for like an hour and I'm not sur if it's actually doing anything or not.

P.S Pycharm, upadtes, postgresql are all installed and working

Comment: It takes less than 1 hour.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93218/discussion-between-csmu-and-kanga).

Comment: ok thanks man I'll try waiting a little bit longer or try adding in the repository